# Beer in Sourdough Starter

Tags: bread, sourdough, sourdough-starter, beer

Would there be any benefit to feeding a sourdough starter with beer instead of or in addition to water?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could I use beer instead of/as well as water in my sourdough?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35425/could-i-use-beer-instead-of-as-well-as-water-in-my-sourdough)

Comment: I read that,  but that addresses adding beer to the sourdough bread dough,  not as part of the starter's regular feeding.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with beer in the starter is that unfiltered beer such as Hefeweizen contains live yeast and that may make a lot of a difference, since that yeast will have a huge head start over any lactobacteria. You may end up with a yeast dough starter culture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is an answer in the question that I linked, which speaks to your question.  However, now that I've read the question again, you are technically correct that it is not a duplicate.  I'll also add that [the folks here](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/34267/beer-starter) seem to think beer in your starter is not very beneficial, but I have found nothing definitive. Perhaps you could create two starters, one with water and one with beer, then bake two identical loaves and report your results as an answer here.

Comment: I recently did this with a Witbier and found no substantial differences other than taste... Which is obviously subjective as to whether it's better that my bread tasted slightly of beer